# memoir tutorials or introductions

Tags: memoir, tutorials

I'm looking for `memoir` tutorials or introductions. The main manual is a wonderful piece of documentation, but at nearly 600 pages it is a bit overwhelming as a starting place. Likewise the more examples I can find (with associated code) the more quickly I can move to the real work of typesetting the book in question---a collection of short stories gathered together in one place for the first time.

Comment: Just get started and ask on a need to know basis. Possibly of interest, though not about `memoir`: [unexpected applications: Typesetting modern & contemporary poetry with Latex](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/24/06.pdf)

Comment: Why not just start typesetting the book and consult the manual as and when you need it. I presume you have some understanding of LaTeX, in which case, you should be able to just jump straight into using `memoir`

Comment: I was just wondering if you'd come up with any resources since you asked this question?

Answer (score 4):

There's a video on zeeba.tv of a presentation by Steve Peter:

[Introduction to memoir](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/introduction-to-memoir/)

**Description:** This presentation serves as a gentle introduction to Peter Wilson’s memoir class, an alternative to the standard LaTeX classes. Memoir is quite flexible, and makes it easy to create beautiful book, article, and report designs, without having to search for, install, and load numerous third-party packages.

Comment: It is well done, but I'm a text sort of person and I'm still hoping for something not widely known out there. I've assembled about 4 or 5 pdfs so that is a start (lots of printing with a trip or two to Kinko's for binding :) ) Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @hsmyers: it would be great if you would share the links to the pdfs here. Perhaps answer your own question posting the links you found until now.