# Quick introduction to memoir class

Tags: memoir, tutorials

I'm planning to use the `memoir` class for writing  a small technical book on computer programming. I just downloaded the `memoir` manual. Unfortunately it is very big and will take a long time to get started. What are some good tutorials on the `memoir` class?

Comment: What do you want? Read l2short to learn the basics.

Comment: Quick tutorial on memoir class regarding how to write small books

Comment: Just write and look up the stuff you need to change. I usually ask students to just write, then we can alter the layout later. There is nothing special in writing with `memoir` (in most cases)

Comment: Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21918/memoir-tutorials-or-introductions.