# Guides and tips for starting off with the Memoir class?

Tags: memoir, books, book-design

So I don't know if this is an appropriate question to ask here, but let's see how it goes.

I would like to know if there are other resources to getting started with the Memoir class in LaTeX. I've tried reading part of the 600 page manual, but eventually it felt like I should only be there to consult particular functionalities.

I've read this post here [memoir tutorials or introductions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21918/memoir-tutorials-or-introductions) and I didn't really find any of the sources given very useful. I've also been searching around on the internet and I haven't found anything helpful.

Are there any other sources out there that can get me started with Memoir, and help me make the most of the package?

Comment: Any basic latex introduction.

Comment: @Johannes_B but here's the thing: I think my ability to program in latex is reasonable. Perhaps I should have included in the question that I would like to make the most of the class, such as designing title pages and chapters, etc.

Comment: You are much more likely to get answers on concrete problems. As to title pages, designing those aren't that specific to memoir. I tend to always code them by hand in the `titlingpage` env.

Comment: When you say 'I did not find the sources useful' what exactly do you mean by that? They give too little information? Too much? The wrong kind of information? For any of the three, what information are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @Marijn I'm generally looking for sources that could provide a gentler learning curve compared to the manual. One of the sites cited in a comment in the question I put in wasn't very helpful as it just showed some examples of designs without code, so I'm not really learning anything from it.

Comment: @daleif thanks for telling me that. I never knew that designing title pages wasn't part of what memoir covered.

Comment: Peter Wilson who wrote memoir made a large document of various title page designs. One design them via the memoir tools for `\maketitle` I just find it easier to explain to people by just doing it by hand.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages?lang=en

Comment: Not really a tutorial, but Peter Wilson also has a document about book design (`texdoc memdesign` should find it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
%....
\end{document}
```

you will get the same output as

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
% ....
\end{document}
```

except that the ToC, LoF and LoT will be listed in the ToC (but you can stop that happening).

Hopefully you are able to code with the `book` class; if not I suggest you learn to do that from the various "getting started" guides or Leslie Lamport's excellent LaTeX book.

In the manual I tried to provide a chapter dealing with specific topics. You mention designing chapters; there is much information, and code, on this in chapter 6 *Document divisions*.

Don't try and read the whole manual in one go, pick out the bits that you are interested in.

Comment: Mr. Wilson? Oh my goodness, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think my best bet is to just stick to the manual and read it from the start, all the way to the end. AFAICS, there doesn't seem to be a gentler introduction to the document class. So I guess I should just accept this fact, put my best foot forward and grind through it.